# Counterexample to Peano's theorem in infinite dimension

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Would you like a counter example that Peano's theorem does not apply to spaces with infinite dimension.

Peano theorem: Let E be a space with finite dimension, consider a point $(t_0,x_0) \in \Re \times E$, constants $ a, b > $ 0 and a apliacação $$F: [t_0 - a, t_0 + a] \times B_b[x_0] \longrightarrow E$$
For every $ M> $ 0 checking:
$$sup {||F(t,x)||;(t,x) \in [t_0 - a, t_0 + a] \times B_b[x_0]} < M$$
the Cauchy problem:
$$x'(t)=F(t,x(t))$$
$$x(t_0)=x_0$$
admits at least one solution in inetrvalo:
$$[t_0 - \min(a,\frac{b}{M}),t_0 + \min(a,\frac{b}{M}) $$
Will be of great help. Thank you very much.